# Using Parametric Type in Implicit for Type Classes in Scala

Tags: scala, types

I am trying to learn more about **TypeClasses** in Scala and came up with this example

```
trait Cons[T] {
    def cons(t1: T, t2: T):T
}

object Cons {
    implicit object StringCons extends Cons[String] {
        override def cons(t1: String, t2: String): String = t1 + t2
    }

    implicit object ListCons extends Cons[List[_]] {
        override def cons(t1: List[_], t2: List[_]): List[_] = t1 ++ t2
    }

    implicit object IntCons extends Cons[Int] {
        override def cons(t1: Int, t2: Int): Int = Integer.parseInt(t1.toString + t2.toString)
    }
}

def Cons[T](t1: T, t2: T)(implicit c: Cons[T]):T = {
    c.cons(t1, t2)
}

Cons("abc", "def") // abcdef
Cons(1, 2) // 12
Cons(List(1,2,3),List(4,5,6)) // does not work, as the expected type is List[Int]
```

When I created `ListCons` I explicitly have set the type of `List[_]` which is if I understand correctly is **existential types** and is equivalent to Java wildcard which means it is of some type and we do not care.

Now the question is why this did not work. Is there a way to make it work. Or maybe there is some fundamental misunderstanding by me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `Cons(List(1,2,3),List(4,5,6))` doesn't work is because by type inference rules it means `Cons[List[Int]](List[Int](1,2,3), List[Int](4,5,6))`, so it specifically needs an implicit `Cons[List[Int]]`, and a `Cons[List[_]]` is not a `Cons[List[Int]]`.

`Cons[List[_]]` *would* be a `Cons[List[Int]]` if `Cons` was contravariant (declared as `Cons[-T]`), but it can't be contravariant because it has a method returning `T` (unless you cheat with `@uncheckedVariance`, and you shouldn't).

The correct way to make it work is to replace `ListCons` with

```
implicit def listCons[T]: Cons[List[T]] = new Cons[List[T]] {
    override def cons(t1: List[T], t2: List[T]): List[T] = t1 ++ t2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a higher kinded types which will enable you to capture your type:

Here is my attempt:

```
trait Cons[T] {
  def cons(t1: T, t2: T): T
}

trait HigherKindCons[M[_]] {
  def cons[T](t1: M[T], t2: M[T]): M[T]
}

object Cons {
  implicit object StringCons extends Cons[String] {
    override def cons(t1: String, t2: String): String = t1 + t2
  }

  implicit object ListCons extends HigherKindCons[List] {
    override def cons[T](t1: List[T], t2: List[T]): List[T] = t1 ++ t2
  }

  implicit object OptCons extends HigherKindCons[Option] {
    override def cons[T](t1: Option[T], t2: Option[T]): Option[T] = t1 orElse t2
  }

  implicit object IntCons extends Cons[Int] {
    override def cons(t1: Int, t2: Int): Int =  Integer.parseInt(t1.toString + t2.toString)
  }
}


import Cons._

def Cons[T](t1: T, t2: T)(implicit c: Cons[T]):T = {
  c.cons(t1, t2)
}

def Cons[T, M[_]](t1: M[T], t2: M[T])(implicit c: HigherKindCons[M]): M[T] = {
  c.cons(t1, t2)
}


Cons[String]("abc", "def") // abcdef
Cons(1, 2) // 12
Cons(List(1,2,3),List(4,5,6))
Cons(List("a", "b"),List("c", "d", "e")) // as the expected type is List[String]
Cons(Some(1), None)
```

### Output:

```
res0: String = abcdef
res1: Int = 12
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
res3: List[String] = List(a, b, c, d, e)
res4: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```